# How to prove the best polynomial approximation operator is continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, approximation-theory, nonlinear-analysis

For any function $f\in C[0,1]$, it is well known that there exist an unique polynomial $p^{*}\in P_n[0,1]$ such that $||p^{*}-f||_{\infty}\leq ||p-f||_{\infty}$ for any $p\in P_n[0,1]$. In this fashion, one can define an operator $A_n: C[0,1]\mapsto P_n[0,1]$ as
$$
A_n(f):={\rm argmin}_{p\in P_n[0,1]}||f-p||_{\infty}.
$$

For a fixed $f\in C[0,1]$, how to prove that there exists a constant $C$ depending on $f$ and $n$ such that
$$
||A_n(f)-A_n(\tilde{f})||_{\infty}\leq C||f-\tilde{f}||_{\infty},\quad \forall\tilde{f}\in C[0,1].
$$

Comment: Is $A_n$ linear?

Comment: No, it is not linear, since the underlying norm is supremum norm.